# Using python to get DB2 list db directory on a remote server

Tags: python, db2, remote-access

I want to get the list of DBs on a remote server with a python script. 
I know I can connect to a certain db with

```
import ibm_db
ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=name;HOSTNAME=host;PORT=60000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=username;
            PWD=password;", "", "")
```

however I want to only connect to an instance and then do "db2 list db directory" to get the DB names. 
Meaning change to the instance user and set off that command or preferably use a python module that can do just that. I only need the names no real connection to a database.

The result should be an array with all database names in that instance.

Any ideas or help?

Thank you

Comment: But a loop with open a close connection is not enough?

Comment: I don't know the names of the databases, that is what I want to get

Comment: Uhm...on Sql Server there is a master db by Default...in db2?..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such function in [python-ibmdb API](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/wiki/APIs) and actually not even in [full Db2 API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.api.doc/doc/r0001915.html). The only "workaround" I could think of would be UDF deployed on the remote database that uses `db2DbDirOpenScan` to access the catalog and return the info via the connection that is already established.